# To get the age from date of birth in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 3 columns with `Age`, `month`, `Date of Birth` I want to get `Age` from `DateofBirth` textbox using stored procedure calculate age with month inserted.

eg:

```
DateofBirth = 25/05/1987 (DD/MM/YYYY)
Age=24
Month=3
```

plz give solution

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please give us what you already have - we're not here to just write your code - we can help if you have a concrete problem - but those "gimme the code" questions aren't likely to be answered....

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the following post:

[Get Age from Date of Birth](http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2007/08/10/3235.aspx)

I have used the method described to retrieve the age and then used the [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function to retrieve the month.

```
DECLARE @dateOfBirth DATETIME
SET @dateOfBirth = '05/25/1987'

DECLARE @age INT
SET @age =  FLOOR(DATEDIFF(DAY, @dateOfBirth, GETDATE()) / 365)

DECLARE @month INT
SET @month = DATEPART(MM, @dateOfBirth)

SELECT @age as Age, @month as [Month]
```